# Galois group of $x^4+7x+7$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, quartics

How can I compute the Galois group of $x^4+7x+7$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? I believe it can be done using some general results about discriminants and cubic resolvants such as in this document: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf#page6

However I would prefer to do a more “direct” computation. By direct I mean something not using discriminants (or the general formulas for a quartics roots either). Usually though this involves being able to deduce what some of the roots are explicitly and I don’t know how to do this for this particular polynomial. Maybe this approach isn’t viable, if that’s the case then at least knowing that would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds a bit strange like " I want to solve a quadratic equation, however I would prefer something not using discriminants". Why would you want to avoid an explicit formula or algorithm for the Galois group? Keith Conrad's article gives an explicit answer for the Galois group of $X^4+7X+7$. Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627996/finding-galois-group-of-a-4-degree-polynomial) is helpful, too.

Comment: I would like to avoid it as find the formulas hard to remember (I am preparing for an exam in a few months) and I have been able to solve problems in the past such as these without the use of these formulas. So I was interested to see if there is a different approach.

Comment: If you want to compute Galois groups you really should understand discriminants. I don’t mean memorize an explicit formula for quartic discriminants, but know how the discriminant is related to the Galois groups being in $A_n$ or not. Has this “exam” really asked for Galois group calculations over $\mathbf Q$ requiring explicit discriminant calculations of polynomials not of the form $x^n - a$? You certainly should need the general quartic formula: I wrote that file and I don’t know the quartic formula.

Comment: It’s a preliminary exam so I just have to be able compute Galois groups. In general I can use any method. Butfor example with polynomials of the form $x^n-a$ since the roots are just some nth root of a and then roots of unity I generally can compute the Galois group using fairly elementary and ad hoc methods by just looking at the roots and various intermediate extensions.

Comment: What are some *actual* polynomials appearing on past prelim exams in your department? I would be shocked that you’d be expected to work out the Galois group over $\mathbf Q$ by hand of something like $x^4+7x+7$ involving computation of cubic resolvents.

Comment: This is an actual polynomial. However the actual wording of the question was to show the Galois group is $S_4$. There was another part before it asking to find the degree of the splitting field over the field of three elements. (I computed that this was 6.) There may have been some trick using this fact though I am unaware of it if it’s there.

Comment: An alternative along the route described by @user714237 is to observe that the polynomial is irreducible modulo $p=2$, so the corresponding Frobenius element is a $4$-cycle. Together with the $3$-cycle we get from $p=3$ it is enough to conclude $G=S_4$. Whether Frobenius elements are covered in your course may depend on how much ivy your school has. The result (due to Dedekind) is covered in Jacobson's Basic Algebra I, so probably nearly all grad programs go through it. Nevertheless, I would not ask a question like this at a qual without checking that $p=2$ and $p=3$ suffice :-)

Comment: Aha this makes sense. I appreciate both of your responses. I think this is about what the authors of the exam had in mind. I will also study up on discriminants and resultant though, thank you all.